# MS-Access: How to open forms in a given panel of the main frame rather than opening a new tab or pop up dialog?

Tags: user-interface, ms-access

presently I have a main form containing **some commands that open other forms or reports as pop up frames**.
I would like to change the way to open those forms: instead of opening them in a tab or a pop up, **i would like them to appear in a panel of my main window.**
Thanks for your help!
[image]

Comment: Navigation pane is doing exactly what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

In your panel, have a *subform control*.

Let each button assign the name of the form to display to the property *SourceObject* of this subform control.